# How can i Boot my VMware WIN 7 in a new machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, vmware

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with VMware windows 7 installed. I moved my hard disk to another computer and i am not able to play vmware machine. I get this message:

Virtualized Intel VT-x/EPT is not supported on this platform.
Continue without virtualized Intel VT-x/EPT?  Yes or No.

if i click yes, it says:
Virtualized performance counters are incompatible with binary translation.
Virtualized performance counters are not supported on the host CPU type.
Virtualized performance counters require architectural performance monitoring version 3 or greater.
Virtualized performance counters require at least one available functioning counter.
Module VPMC power on failed.
Failed to start the virtual machine. and turns off vmware player and if i click no it also turns off vmware player.

how do i make it work?

Comment: Which processor and mainboard do you use in the new machine? Maybe you need to activate `Intel Virtualization Technology` in BIOS

Comment: I was formally using an hp dm4 with intel core i5 and then the new machine is: Processor (Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4500 @ 2.30GHz × 2 ) and Graphics (Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset )

Comment: The previous machine was hp pavilion dm4 with intel core i5-processor and the new machine is dell inspiron N5030 with Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4500 @ 2.30GHz × 2 processor

Comment: I also get this on one of the errors: Virtualized performance counters are incompatible with binary translation.
Virtualized performance counters are not supported on the host CPU type.
Virtualized performance counters require architectural performance monitoring version 3 or greater.
Virtualized performance counters require at least one available functioning counter.
Module VPMC power on failed.
Failed to start the virtual machine.

Comment: According to [Intels CPU Specs](http://ark.intel.com/products/42925/Intel-Pentium-Processor-T4500-1M-Cache-2_30-GHz-800-MHz-FSB) your CPU doesn't support the Intel Virtualization Technology. You can't use this VM.